# Sending html email with in-line image attachment causes outlook to block the message (potentially unsafe attachment)

Tags: laravel, email, amazon-web-services, html-email, amazon-ses

I am trying to send a HTML email in Laravel 5.2 using `Amazon SES` like this:

```
Mail::send('emails.test', [
    'header_logo' => public_path('assets/images/default_email_header.jpg'),
    'html_email' => 'hello world! Email <b>html test</b>'
], function($message) {
    $message
        ->to('latheesan@domain.com', 'Latheesan K')
        ->subject('Test ses email');
});
```

And my mail view blade **emails/test.blade.php** file contains this line:

```
<img src="<?php echo $message->embed($header_logo); ?>" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<br>
{!! $html_email !!}
```

When this email is sent; it ends up in junk folder with this message:

> Outlook blocked access to the following potentially unsafe attachment: default_email_header.jpg

Any idea why this happens? if i move the message back into inbox, the email looks right. But why is it unsafe? why is it always ending up in junk folder?

Comment: Is that outlook your office account?

Comment: yes it is. We use office 365. but why is `.jpg` in-line image attachment considered unsafe?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is not issue with the image or your SES application. This is happening due to your outlook security acting up which might be set up by your office IT.

Here is some trouble shooting.

https://www.itsupportguides.com/office-2013/outlook-2013-how-to-unblock-potentially-unsafe-attachments/

Here is another support doc from Microsoft.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/829982